# g_gmock_mutex is not a type

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googlemock

I'm trying to run some unitesting that uses gmock/gtest and I'm getting the following error:

```
    /usr/include/gmock/gmock-spec-builders.h:134:41: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
   bool VerifyAndClearExpectationsLocked()
                                         ^
    /usr/include/gmock/gmock-spec-builders.h:135:38: error: ‘g_gmock_mutex’ is not a type
           GTEST_EXCLUSIVE_LOCK_REQUIRED_(g_gmock_mutex);
```

There's a similar question where the solution is to use the same version both for gmock and gtest. But this is not my case since I'm already using the same versions for both packages. Right now my setup is:

```
google-mock:amd64 1.6.0+svn437-0ubuntu5
libgtest-dev  1.6.0-1ubuntu6
```

I can reproduce the issue by the following simple example:

```
# include<gtest/gtest.h>
# include<gmock/gmock.h>

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `return0;` ? Maybe `return 0;` ?

Comment: No, it was just an copy&paste error ... fixed

Comment: "copy&paste error"? what the ... is that?

Comment: Those are not latest versions. Is there some specific reason to use older versions?

Comment: These are the default packages provided the default mint installation (it's based on ubuntu 14.04). I would like to use the packages provided by the system instead of installing them manually whenever it's possible.

Comment: That is a five year old version, I would strongly suggest using the latest version from github. googlemock is absorbed into googletest. All you need to do is checkout googletest repo and build it using provided instructions.

Comment: Yeh, I did that and it worked :-) .. Looks like eve when the packages versions are the same their content is not synchronized. Thanks for helping.